# Embed SSL Certificate into self hosted .NET server application (WCF/SignalR): How?

Tags: wcf, signalr

We have a stand alone web socket server built in .NET 4.51 and SignalR.

Works great.

We can do SSL fine by referencing a certificate in the windows machine store.

Fine.

Our project requires that our exe (the web socket server built w SignalR) be portable, and able to serve as an SSL server everywhere it runs, without interacting with the certificate store on the OS.

Possible?

How close can we get to this?

(Yes, we understand that the private key, etc, will be embedded in the exe, and could be stolen.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is the answer:
[WCF Certificates without Certificate Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406136/wcf-certificates-without-certificate-store)

However, we will accept a detailed response here!